# How to access 'key' inside of a Swift dictionary

Tags: swift

I have the following dictionary:

```
var data = [
        ["Balance": ""],
        ["Borrowed": ""],
        ["Interest Rate": ""],
        ["Monthly Payment": ""],
        ["Payment Date": ""]
    ]
```

I'm using this dictionary to render a tableView, and want to access the left side of it (i.e. the key) and render it inside of each table cell.

So for example, the first cell would be able to pick 'Balance', the second 'Borrowed' and so on.

How can I do this? There doesn't seem to be an obvious solution to this?

Comment: Please, use structs instead of dictionaries. Swift is not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` (an array of dictionaries) isn't a very convenient data structure to work with, in terms of accessing the keys and populating a table view.

If you can change to another data structure, I would suggest an array of key-value pairs:

```
var data = [
    ("Balance", ""),
    ("Borrowed", ""),
    ("Interest Rate", ""),
    ("Monthly Payment", ""),
    ("Payment Date", "")
]
```

If something else is producing this data, and you have no control over that "something else", you can turn the array of dictionaries into the above by doing:

```
var data = arrayOfDictionaries.flatMap { $0 }
```

Then, given an index path, you can easily access the "key" and "value". Suppose that the table view only has one section and each row displays one key-value pair...

```
let (key, value) = data[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = key
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let item = data[indexPath.row]
cell.lbl.text = item.keys.first
```

Answer (score 0):

so what you have here is a multiple dictionary inside the list. You can iterate over it in order to get the keys like that :

```
for element in data {
    let keys = element.keys
    let key = keys.first! // Each dictionary has only one key.
    print(key)
}
```

Now, because you will use a Table View you will have an indexPath. You can get the specific key for each of them by using the indexPath.row.

```
let key = data[indexPath.row]
// Now you can display your key however you like.
```